# Backbone routing from external source possible without hash?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, backbone.js, hash, router

I am using the Backbone router to create a route like this:

```
city/:name
http://www.mysite.com/#city/Paris (single page webapp using index.html)
```

However, I would ideally like the routing to do:

```
city:/name
http://www.mysite.com/city/Paris
```

I have enabled pushState for the backbone router. However, navigating to http://www.mysite.com/#city/Paris works fine, but http://www.mysite.com/city/Paris gives me a 404.

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/'});
```

I notice with pushState enabled, once http://www.mysite.com/#city/Paris is loaded, any further navigation omits the #, which is what I want. However, if I bookmark http://www.mysite.com/city/Paris and try to load it, I get a 404.

Am I missing a step here? I've tried to configure my .htaccess file with the following settings but that doesn't seem to fix anything:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (?!^index\.html)^(.+)$ /index.html#$1 [L,NC,R,NE]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: You need to make sure the correct content is being served up on the initial request. Backbone can't do that for you. Your server has to respond to `/city/Paris` with whatever content it normally responds to with `/index`.

Comment: Ah, so it is a .htaccess config step that I am missing then?

How do I forward any www.mysite.com/city/Paris requests to www.mysite.com/index.html/#city/Paris?